# wxWidgets 3.1.4 native on M1 get setup.h missing

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets, apple-m1

I have an M1 Mac. I downloaded wxWidgets 3.1.4 tar, uncompressed, do simple the `./configure; make; make install`.

Then when compiling my project I get the error:

```
platform.h:160:10 fatal error: 'wx/setup.h' file not found.
```

What do I need to add to the `./configure` so this file is generated?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using `wx-config --cxxflags` (nor `--libs`, for linking) when building your project. You need to do it.

See also `wxwin.m4` file for some helpful macros if you're using autoconf.

Comment: Your correct I am not - simply "./configure"  - I know nothing about wx-config.  IT would seem that Xcode has all those options set "wx-config --cxxflags" - but there still is no  /usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/setup.h file .

Comment: If you ran `make install` without errors, this file should exist. Please check your build log to see if you didn't miss some error in it.

Comment: @JGeis, you need to manually add the path to this file. What you should do is run in Terminal `wx-config --cxxflags` and `-wx-config --libs` and add the result of those 2 command to the Xcode project you are using to byuild your software.

Comment: In file included from /Users/msgnet/mac-pcalert/src/PCAlert/wxImageLoader.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/msgnet/mac-pcalert/src/PCAlert/wxImageLoader.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/wx.h:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/defs.h:45:
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/platform.h:160:10: fatal error: 'wx/setup.h' file not found
#include "wx/setup.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.                    This is the error I get.  I have not a solution to setup.h not existing.

Comment: ` /usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/setup.h` should have been created by `make install`. If it's not there, `make install` must have failed and given an error that you're not showing us.